# get_or_create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, django, django-models

Last time I checked, (h) one argument:

```
for entry in f['entries']:
    h = {'feed':self, 'link': entry['link'],'title':entry['title'],
         'summary':entry['summary'],
         'updated_at':datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(entry['updated_parsed']))}

    en = Entry.objects.get_or_create(h)
```

This code is failing with the error in the title. What can I check for?

Answer (score 14):

`get_or_create` takes keyword arguments only. If the arguments are in a dict, you can call it with:

```
en = Entry.objects.get_or_create(**h)
```

Or you can put the keyword arguments directly:

```
en = Entry.objects.get_or_create(name=value, ....)
```

The reason the error message told you that you supplied two arguments is that there is an implicit `self` parameter passed to the function.